# c++ rest cascblanca: make test failes on debian/ubuntu

Tags: c++, rest, https, makefile, casablanca

I have problems getting the http-client to work. I have installed the C++ REST SDK from [this](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20and%20Build%20on%20Linux&referringTitle=Documentation) guide.

My OS is Debian GNU/Linux 8.3 (jessie). I have tested on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, too,

The problem occurs after building the libraries and running the tests. With 'make test' the output looks like that:

```
Start 1: httpclient_test
1/8 Test #1: httpclient_test ..................***Failed   22.87 sec

Start 2: httplistener_test
2/8 Test #2: httplistener_test ................   Passed    1.11 sec

Start 3: json_test
3/8 Test #3: json_test ........................   Passed    0.03 sec

Start 4: pplx_test
4/8 Test #4: pplx_test ........................   Passed    1.37 sec

Start 5: streams_test
5/8 Test #5: streams_test .....................   Passed    5.30 sec

Start 6: uri_test
6/8 Test #6: uri_test .........................   Passed    0.02 sec

Start 7: utils_test
7/8 Test #7: utils_test .......................   Passed    0.02 sec

Start 8: websocketclient_test
8/8 Test #8: websocketclient_test .............   Passed    8.81 sec


88% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 8

Total Test time (real) =  39.53 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - httpclient_test (Failed)

When running './test_runner *_test.so' the errors are:
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/authentication_tests.cpp:643: error: Failure in set_user_options_asio_https: Unhandled exception: Error in SSL handshake FAILED
Test case authentication_tests:set_user_options_asio_https FAILED
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:56: error: Failure in outside_cnn_dot_com: CHECK_EQUAL(status_codes::OK, response.status_code()) where status_codes::OK=200 and response.status_code()=302
 FAILED
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:61: error: Failure in outside_cnn_dot_com: CHECK_EQUAL(status_codes::OK, response.status_code()) where status_codes::OK=200 and response.status_code()=302
 FAILED
Test case outside_tests:outside_cnn_dot_com FAILED
Starting test case outside_tests:outside_google_dot_com...
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:73: error: Failure in outside_google_dot_com: CHECK_EQUAL(status_codes::OK, response.status_code()) where status_codes::OK=200 and response.status_code()=302
 FAILED
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:73: error: Failure in outside_google_dot_com: CHECK_EQUAL(status_codes::OK, response.status_code()) where status_codes::OK=200 and response.status_code()=302
 FAILED
Test case outside_tests:outside_google_dot_com FAILED
Starting test case outside_tests:multiple_https_requests...
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:87: error: Failure in multiple_https_requests: CHECK_EQUAL(status_codes::OK, response.status_code()) where status_codes::OK=200 and response.status_code()=302
 FAILED
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:87: error: Failure in multiple_https_requests: CHECK_EQUAL(status_codes::OK, response.status_code()) where status_codes::OK=200 and response.status_code()=302
 FAILED
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:87: error: Failure in multiple_https_requests: CHECK_EQUAL(status_codes::OK, response.status_code()) where status_codes::OK=200 and response.status_code()=302
 FAILED
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:87: error: Failure in multiple_https_requests: CHECK_EQUAL(status_codes::OK, response.status_code()) where status_codes::OK=200 and response.status_code()=302
 FAILED
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:87: error: Failure in multiple_https_requests: CHECK_EQUAL(status_codes::OK, response.status_code()) where status_codes::OK=200 and response.status_code()=302
 FAILED
Test case outside_tests:multiple_https_requests FAILED
Starting test case outside_tests:reading_google_stream...
[...]/casablanca/Release/tests/functional/http/client/outside_tests.cpp:107: error: Failure in reading_google_stream: CHECK_EQUAL(strcmp((const char *) chars, "<!doctype html><html itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.org/WebPage\""), 0) where strcmp((const char *) chars, "<!doctype html><html itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.org/WebPage\"")=1 and 0=0
 FAILED
Test case outside_tests:reading_google_stream FAILED

**** authentication_tests:set_user_options_asio_https FAILED ****

**** outside_tests:outside_cnn_dot_com FAILED ****

**** outside_tests:outside_google_dot_com FAILED ****

**** outside_tests:multiple_https_requests FAILED ****

**** outside_tests:reading_google_stream FAILED ****
```

All other tests pass. I have no idea what I am about to do about this. On Windows my Code is working fine, on Linux I'm getting errors when sending http requests with http_client.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?